# Meteor, $(...).openModal is not a function

Tags: jquery, meteor, materialize

I got my project/app working on my phone now with.

```
meteor run android
```

But getting some error message in the debug/info console.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).openModal is not a function"
```

I tried to add newest materialize css and jquery, but that makes no difference. What can be wrong?
I tried to make a workaround, with

```
$("#decline").modal();
```

but that gives the same TypeError message only for modal is not a function.
So it has something to do with jquery, but i don't know what.
Some suggestions for me?

Comment: Did you try importing a jquery modal library?

Comment: I definded jquery script (<cdn>/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js) in main.html. I ran meteor install jquery. /.meteor/local/versions says jquery@1.11.11 (i dont know this is correct?).

Comment: ok. you would need to add jquery modal dependency as well https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js

Comment: I added this package to script in main.html but still "TypeError: $(...).modal is not function". Changed showModal to modal as  described in "https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal".

Comment: Your welcome. It's advised to vote on what worked for you so others can benefit from it.